# how to define and access array in grails from config.groovy file

Tags: amazon-web-services, grails, groovy

I have a harcoded value in one of my controller

```
public regions = ['code1','code2']
```

Now have to read these values from `config.groovy` file,

I tried to define in `config.groovy`:-

`region = "code1,code2"`

in mycontroller :-

```
def aws = grailsApplication.config.awsRegions; 
public awsRegions = aws.split(",")
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

In the Config.groovy you can do:

```
awsRegions = ['Region 1', 'Region 2']
```

Then in your Controller you can do:

```
def awsRegions = grailsApplication.config.awsRegions
```

Your changes are not working in the comments with Sathish Kumar because you are calling your property "awsRegion" in Config.groovy and accessing it with "grailsApplicatio.config.awsRegion**s**". The keys must match.

Answer (score 0):

1

```
public regions = ['code1','code2']
```

should that not be

```
public List regions = ['code1','code2']
or 
public List<String> regions = ['code1','code2']
```

In the world of groovy / grails `public` is not required so long as it is not a static variable

2

```
def aws = grailsApplication.config.awsRegions; 
public awsRegions = aws.split(",")
```

When in doubt :

```
def aws = grailsApplication.config.awsRegions; 
println  "aws is ${aws} object class is ${aws.getClass()}"
```

You should find the println returns [element,e2,e3] within a List already. The `getClass()` of something tells you what it actually is so you should find it is already a list and does not require the additional split which you would do on a flat string

Comment: I declared in config.groovy file as 

`awsRegion = "code2,code1"` and I used this
`def aws = grailsApplication.config.awsRegions` but it didn't work

Comment: right instead declare it like you did in controller so `myKey.awsRegion=['code1','code2']` then when you call it - it is returned as a list . here is an example https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/conf/SampleConfig.groovy#L83-L89

Comment: I declared in config.groovy file as `awsRegion = ['code2', 'code1']` and I used this `def aws = grailsApplication.config.awsRegions` but still its not working

Comment: what does `println grailsApplication.config` show  do you see your object or any config object ?  if so `grailsApplication.config?.each{k,v-> println "${k} ${v.getClass()}" }`